# How to replace one substring in multiple strings in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have multiple strings:

```
string1 = "ab"
string2 = "db"
string3 = "eb"
```

How do I replace the same substring in all of them? Let's say I need to replace"b" with "c". I can sure do the following, but is there a neat one-line solution?

```
string1 = string1.replace("b", "c")
string2 = string2.replace("b", "c")
string3 = string3.replace("b", "c")
```

Comment: sounds to me like you want to store your strings in a data structure like a list rather than keeping them all as individual variables; then you can just do `strings = [string.replace("b", "c') for string in strings]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string1,string2,string3=[string.replace('b','c') for string in [string1,string2,string3]]
```

Try this neat list comprehension one-liner

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class and create classmethods in list comprehension:

```
class String:
   def __init__(self, s):
       self.s = s
   def replace(self, old, new):
      return self.s.replace(old, new)


string1 = "ab"
string2 = "db"
string3 = "eb"
l = [String(i).replace("b", "c") for i in [string1, string2, string3]]
```

Output:

```
['ac', 'dc', 'ec']
```

Comment: what is advantage of using class in this example?